# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'key' después de actualizar a PHP 7.4

Tags: reactjs, php7, warnings

En una aplicación *React* que usa api *PHP* (que actualicé desde *5.6* a PHP *7.4* ) obtengo en consola del navegador al realizar pedido de datos:

> *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)*

y en error_log del server :

> *PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'clave4'.*

La línea de código que me señala el error es la siguiente:

```
$array['clave'][0]['clave2'] = array('clave'=>$var,'clave3'=>count($array['clave4']));
```

Uso la misma lógica en otras partes del código pero esta es la única que me da este error, ¿que podrá ser?

Probé declarar **$array** explicitamente como un *array* y obtengo el mismo error.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda y comentarios.

Comment: Eso de `mi_clave` lo debes haber cambiado, porque no aparece en esa linea. ¿A cual corresponde exactamente?  Que no sea el **count**, que a partir de 7.2 necesita realizarse solo sobre **arrays** u objetos que usen la clase **Countable**, y no objetos sin ella. Si necesitas hacer un **count** sobre un objeto sin la clase esa debes hacerlo asi:  `count((array)$array['clave4'])` suponiendo que dicha clave exista.

Comment: Hola, si, tenés razón, ahora lo edito. La clave que me da error es 'clave4'

Comment: Pues prueba lo del **count** defininiendo lo que venga despues como un array con el **(array)** delante... y si eso no te funciona es que esa clave no existe, y tendras que revisar de donde viene y porque no existe

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($array);` y revisa lo que contiene tu array realmente.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus comentarios. Al final, gracias al `var_dump($array)` pude ver en la pestaña Network del navegador que estaba obteniendo un string.

Pero, aparte, me apareció ahí mismo un error de SQL:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'columna' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".

Agregué la línea `sql-mode=""` en el archivo **`my.conf`** del server, lo que finalmente solucionó el problema.

Comment: *Agregué la línea sql-mode="" en el archivo my.conf del server, lo que finalmente solucionó el problema.* Pues NO, eso NO ha solucionado tu problema, más bien has otorgado a tu base de datos una **configuración demasiado permisiva** que te llevará a escribir consultas no estandarizadas, no optimizadas y que podrían ser problemáticas a largo plazo dentro de MySQL, o si necesitas en un futuro migrar tu BD a otro SGBD que no será tan permisivo como MySQL. Deberías considerar resolver este problema escribiendo una consulta correcta, agrupando del modo adecuado.

Comment: Ok, no lo sabía. Gracias por mencionarlo. Voy a intentar cambiar las consultas para no tener que usar esa configuración.

Comment: Será la mejor opción. Es simple: cuando usas `GROUP BY` el SGBD debe saber, en caso de que haya más de un resultado posible, qué resultado elegir. Eso lo puedes hacer agregando los posibles repetidos en el grupo, o indicando mediante una función de agregación (`MAX`, `MIN`, `GROUP_CONCAT`) cuál/es elegirá. Tu caso en realidad es un error, que MySQL permite "resolver" aparentemente poniendo una configuración que al final te llevará a practicar consultas mal escritas. En otros SGBD esas consultas no funcionarán de ningún modo.